# Performing Chi-Square test (or similar) across a spatial grid in R

Tags: r, statistics, geospatial, spatial, statistical-test

I have a dataframe in R where each row is an sf-formatted geospatial polygon in the United States. I know the number of venomous snakes and the number of non-venomous snakes seen in each polygon. I also know the diets of birds in each polygon. Specifically, I know how many non-venomous snakes birds ate, and how many venomous snakes birds ate. My goal is to evaluate whether birds are eating fewer venomous snakes than would be expected given venomous snakes' abundance in each polygon. That is, are birds randomly eating snakes or are they deliberately avoiding potentially dangerous snakes in favor of harmless snakes.

See below for an example dataframe (though without the column describing each spatial polygon; I'm not sure how to recreate that for this example).

```
 df <- data.frame(grid_id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  n_venomous = c(50,50,50,50,50),
                  n_non_venomous = c(50,50,50,50,50),
                  n_eat_venomous = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
                  n_eat_non_venomous = c(40, 40, 40, 40, 40))
> df
  grid_id n_venomous n_non_venomous n_eat_venomous n_eat_non_venomous
1       1         50             50             10                 40
2       2         50             50             10                 40
3       3         50             50             10                 40
4       4         50             50             10                 40
5       5         50             50             10                 40
```

This seems like a relatively simply case of calculating differences between observed and expected values (i.e., if birds weren't choosy, we would expect them to eat the same proportion of venomous and non-venomous snakes as exists in each area). But I imagine I shouldn't just run dozens of individual chi-square tests (I have 50+ different spatial grids). There is also the issue of spatial autocorrelation.

Given my research goal, how should I approach this analysis in R?